# What's the best way to use the SAFE stack and still have a JSON-SPEC API?

Tags: .net, f#, .net-core, json-api

I'd like to use the SAFE stack and F# (https://safe-stack.github.io/) as well as have the API be JSON API compliant (http://jsonapi.org/) Are there any built in tools for accomplishing this?

Comment: Saturn gives you tools for returning JSON responses (though with an `application/json` content type), but AFAIK so far nobody's implemented a JSON API helper. You [could make a feature request](https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn/issues), though.

Comment: OK so it seems as though this is currently not possible? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @tesserakt it might be possible to use an existing aspnet core package if it is a middleware implementation as Giraffe is just a functional framework over aspnet core. The intended benefit over Suave is use of the aspnet core ecosystem and speed improvements.

Comment: @DevonBurriss I'm new to .net/F# so I'd need an example. Ideally I was looking for something that can auto generate controllers based off of the ORM schema. All you would specify are constraints, much like the ruby on rails implementations work. It seems that it's not a "solved" problem in the F# world, at least for now.

Comment: @tesserakt personal preference but I question the usefulness of these kind of json responses (eg. HAL, HATEOS) . Useful but only in some when you have specific types of consumers and building something quite complex. If you are building something complex code generation of end-to-end pipelines is usually to simplistic. If you are looking for the auto gen I would strongly suggest Saturn https://saturnframework.org/ . To add a little context to why I try stay away, by definition you are exposing your model to the client which means you cannot easily change your internals while keeping contract.

Comment: @DevonBurriss You are exposing the model to your client anyway and with this you use representers to figure out which fields to expose. It just gives you the convenience of formatting output in the right way and handling relationships correctly.